# Connecting a surge protection device

Tags: ground, surge-protection, neutral

I've just learned about the surge protection device (SPD). As I was reading about its connection in a three phase line, I came across this scheme:

[image: How it is]

I understand that the SPD's are there to limit the line tension in respect with the PE reference, but why isn't it connected to the line neutral? Each phase's voltage should be measured like this in my mind:

[image: How I see it should be]

Also, isn't the protective ground meant to protect things that are outside the circuit? like other electronics, people etc. against accidental contacts?. How can you intentionally connect the circuit with a reference that is only there for safety?

Answer (score 1):

When connected to Earth Ground as opposed to Neutral ground, the intent is to eliminate Neutral additional inductance and suppress transient noise to ground to reduce EMI interference to nearby radios and mobiles.

Otherwise every switch transfer would sound like lightning hundreds of miles away on AM radio.

the Q of the RLC values depends greatly on R at resonant frequency as the SPD is generally very low Zzt.

Comment: but we are talking about a three phase line tension (more than 100 V) vs a small radio interference. The SPD is meant to protect agains huge surges of tension, for example a lightning striking nearby. And in my case, I'm studying to implement it on a motor powered by a generator, so the distance to the neutral is not that far.

Comment: True but so the shortest path to ground is Earth ground and not Neutral where ESL and EMI are also important. If your case is unique then ok.  Yes and we are talking about big  dv/dt and di/dt so both E&H field noise are dominant.  Industrial noise pollution.  I consulted for a transformer factory once and the Xenon strobe safety flash during HV tests caused all mobile radio reception to be blocked (jammed) (EMI pollution)  ( bad design)

Comment: but beware of earth impedance currents for Vrise and safety.

Comment: Ok. So this is the only reason the SPD is not connected to the neutral?

Comment: Vrise or GPR is explained in a lot more detail here http://www.nemasurge.org/faqs/#grounding

Answer (score 1):

The risk of damage due to voltage surges is not only from line to line voltages but also line to PE.

The placement of the SPD in the top diagram limits the maximum voltage between L1, L2 or L3 AND PE. It inherently also limits the voltage between all combination of L1-L2, L1-L3 etc.

Your proposed scheme does not limit the surge voltage with respect to PE, only line to line.